# Is there a point in memory on the stack where performance drops significantly?

Tags: c++, performance, memory, stack

is there any point in the amount of memory allocation on the stack where performance drops significantly? I understand that if it were on the heap, as your memory moves from L1 to L2 to main memory that the number of cache misses increases dramatically, but what about the stack?

after commenting out every other function, in my personal example, (a game engine) and focusing on calling this line of code every frame on every object:

```cpp
    image.getTrans().x += velocity[VELOCITY_X];
    image.getTrans().y += velocity[VELOCITY_Y];
```

the fps decreases at a constant rate from about `2000 fps` to `200 fps` after going from 0 objects to 1500 objects (which in itself I find to be large for what little is being) but than after adding about 50 or 100 more objects, the fps shoots down to `60 fps` or `50 fps`, and than down to `2 fps` and `1 fps` and worse after adding a few more.

All that is going on here is addition of `velocity[type]` (which is on the stack) to the image's `transformation.type` (which is also on the stack).

Since modern computers can run such an absurd amount of computations per second (about 36 billion I believe) the only solution I can come up with here is that a high percentage of the time, the program is waiting for memory, which I cant understand, since this is all on the stack.

Sorry for any miss used terms here or miss interpretations, I'm relatively new to a lot of the ideas relating to memory

Comment: Too broad to diagnose what's the problem actually. Profile.

Comment: The stack also resides in RAM.

Comment: Your assumptions are incorrect.  Stack/heap has very little to do with L1/L2 cache -- locality and prefetching yes, stack/heap no.  Given that level of misunderstanding, your analysis of your own code has very little reliability.  Sorry, it is difficult to help when all I can see is fog.

Comment: Do the math.  At zero objects to process you have 2000 fps.  At 1500 objects, your rate decreases to 200fps.  Could this be because you have more data to process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, rarely do any compilers or programs allocate memory in L1, L2 or L3 caches.  The simple reason is they are not privy to the addresses. Also, the size of the L1, L2 and L3 caches is a lot smaller than main memory.

In general, the capacity of the stack has very little to do with performance.  The capacity of the stack is often a limitation to function call nesting or recursion, or the amount of local variables that can be stored.

If your stack memory grows towards your heap, you may have issues when running out of stack space (and colliding with the heap) or the heap grows and overwrites your stack.

Allocation of stack memory is often a matter of increasing the value of a stack pointer.  Worst case, this involves loading a value from memory to a register, adjusting the value in the register, then storing back into memory, 3 operations.

Your program may suffer more from the size of an array increasing than the stack allocations.  The larger the array, the more iterations performed on it.  Each iteration breaks the data processing cycle of the processor, which wastes time.

If your data is organized correctly and of the correct size, the *processor* may haul in all the data into it's cache.  If we assume that when data is fetched from memory, by the processor, and placed into the cache, it doesn't load one variable.  Most likely, the processor hauls in enough data to fill in one or more cache lines.  If your array fits into a cache line, the processor has all of your data in its cache with that one load.  If you are accessing array slots that are not next to each other, the processor may have to refetch a different of memory, erasing your existing data (thus degrading performance).

Read up on these topics:

- Optimizing cache performance.
- Data driven design
- Optimizing data cache performance

As always, **profile your code to find the bottlenecks**.  Sometimes, a change in design can have a higher ROI, than a simple code change.

Comment: Changed "SRAM" to "main memory". L1, L2 and L3 are in fact SRAM, whereas main memory is not (it's DRAM).

Comment: On my embedded system, SRAM is main memory.  I don't the technology that our ARM7 SOC uses for its cache.  We don't have DRAM.

Comment: That's rather rare, but still: the term "main memory" covers both the main SRAM in your system (but not its cache SRAM), and the common DRAM main memory used by Cortex-A, x86, x64, POWER, SPARC, etc.